# Magento add to cart - on which page is the form submitted?

Tags: magento

I need to know one thing regarding magento add-to-cart feature. On the product page there is a form which submits your command if you want to buy that product. I need to know the php page that's receiving and parsing the submitted data.

The `action` attribute of the form has a strange URL so I can't really see which php page is doing the job. (ie `http://www.mysite.com/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5wdWxzZWlyYXZpcnR1YWwuY29tLmJyL3Y4L25vdmEvaW5kZXgucGhwL3B1bHNlaXJhLWlkZW50aWZpY2FjYW8vcHVsc2VpcmFzLXBlcnNvbmFsaXphY2FvLWVtLXByZXRvL3B1bHNlaXJhcy1kZS1pZGVudGlmaWNhY2FjYW8tZW0tdHl2ZWsuaHRtbA,,/product/12/` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above URL hit:

```
app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php
```

And function name is: public function addAction(), around 170 line

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the code inside:

`app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php`